# Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Express 12c Japanese Login Page

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I installed "Enterprise Manager Database Express 12c" to my Oracle Database 12c Standart Edition.

When I try to login main page I get an error which is shown as below link

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Zct.jpg)

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFefL.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to change the language from Japanese to EN? or else provide the error in English so that we can help you, or might be you have to wait for some Japanese guy here.

Comment: I am waiting to see login page which is a flash based. I don't know why I see this error page.